# var in single quote PHP

Tags: php, string, var

I'm PHP beginner. I have function('argument');

Argument is string... I need put $var in this function, as argument.

Like:  function('$var')

for example $var = string, result should be: function('string')

I tried several combinations, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You mean `some_function($some_var)`?

Comment: No, I need function('$some_var'), single quote is necessery.

Comment: @user3677220: Why do you say that? Particularly as you've already found it does not work?

Comment: I have: function get_attachment_id_from_url( $argument = '' ), and I need get_attachment_id_from_url('$var'), other case it doesn't work...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, just use `pn_get_attachment_id_from_url( $some_var )` where `$some_var` is the attachment url you want to get the id of. As 'Lightness Races in Orbit' has already clearly explained, you don't need to wrap you variable in `'`s. Right now you're passing the string '$var' to your function which obviously won't work.

Comment: I'm using this function: https://philipnewcomer.net/2012/11/get-the-attachment-id-from-an-image-url-in-wordpress/  This function need argument: pn_get_attachment_id_from_url( 'http://example.com' )

Comment: @user3677220: You're not listening. `'example.com'` is a string. `$var` is (in your case) a string. You may use either. Why don't you give it a go before telling all these experts that they are wrong and that you, a self-described beginner, are right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you drop me correct example of using this function with $var?

Comment: @user3677220 just look at the first line of my comment. 'Lightness Races in Orbit' has explained multiple times why it won't work. Properly read through their answer and comments.

Comment: @user3677220: You have already been given at least two. Your assumption that you need to surround your variable name in single quotes is _incorrect_ and that's all there is to it.

Comment: I know it's incorrect... but when I induce: pn_get_attachment_id_from_url( $some_var ) it doesn't work... Working only with (''), but I haven't idea how remake this function without single quotes..

Comment: @user3677220: Then you must have used the wrong variable name. Stop talking about single quotes. Forget about them. Entirely. Just forget they exist. You are obsessing over something that is completely irrelevant and _will not_ solve your problem. Which book are you learning PHP from?

Answer (score 2):

> No, I need function('$some_var'), single quote is necessery.

Despite your insistence, this is incorrect.

`$some_var` is already a string: you should not be encapsulating it in a string literal. And *if* you did, you'd need `"` instead of `'` in order to get variable interpolation.

This is all described in the PHP manual, so I'm curious as to why you have yet to consult it.